# Why Chrome Developer Tools set such a big viewport size when emulating mobile?

Tags: android, html, css

I have a test document as follows:

```
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

So it's just an empty document. In normal browser mode, I get an nice empty page, no scrolls.

But when I open devtools and turn on mobile emulation (for example, Sony Xperia Z, Z1), I see scroll bars (both horizontal and vertical), and html element size is 980x1742. Where does this come from? Shouldn't it be at least zero height?

Comment: When you look at the devtools without emulating a device, the html element size is not zero in width or height, it's completely dependent on your browser width and height.

Comment: @skrawler - to be precise, it's width is equal to browser width, and height is 8px (because body has 8px margin). But when emulating the device, html width and height seems to come from nowhere, and that screws up the page.

Answer (score 5):

To make your page the exact size of the screen (no zooming or otherwise), place this in the header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

There's some more info about it, as well as additional parameters you may find useful, on Mozilla's developer site [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Viewport_meta_tag).

Comment: I did as you suggested, but in mobile emulation it still has 980x1742 size.

Comment: I have the same problem now, after I have changed vom Bootstrap 3.x to 4.x (and I already had the viewport tag in the header). If I select a device, there is empty space in the width (on the right side) and I have to doubleclick the mobile view in GC to expand the view. In the old version (with BS 3.x) it still work as expected. So.. I think. my problem is related to BS4. Has somebody a tip for me?... thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
```